# SpringCloud + OpenFeign : Cannot use @RequestAttribute to make a call to other app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have a Spring Cloud Feign Client mapping defined as following:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list")
List<PojoVM> getList(@RequestAttribute (name = "cifNumber") String cifNumber);
```

when I call

```
public List<PojoVM> getList() {
  return client.getList("100001");
}
```

Other App receive This OpenFeign app api call as POST, not GET

Is other way to use @RequestAtrribute ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the annotation @RequestAttribute. You should use @RequestParam (or @PathVariable) instead.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list")
List<PojoVM> getList(@RequestParam(name="cifNumber") String cifNumber);
```